# Mocked API response is `undefined` in jest with vue-utils

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

I've got a Vue 3 app which makes an API call and processes the response for adjusting some data fields. The API call is made after the child component emits a custom event, which the parent is listening on. Its working fine, but now I want to test (jest 26, vue-test-utils) it and I'm failing all the time. I'm not able to mock the response, its always `undefined`. Therefore, i cannot expect the changed data fields.

I'm new to jest, but I've think this is the desired way to mock a response. Or am I wrong?

This is my abstracted test code. Have a look at the `open()`-method and how i try to mock its API response.

Structure:

```
-
|- Parent.vue
|- Child.vue
|- api.js
```

Parent.vue

```
<template>
  <Child
    v-for="price in prices"
    :key="price.type"
    :price="price"
    @open="open"
  ></Child>
</template>
<script>
// imports
export default {
  name: "Parent",
  components: {
    Child
  },
  props: ["id"],
  async mounted() {
    // on creation load initial prices
    const pricesDto = await loadPricesFor(this.id);
    this.prices = toPrices(pricesDto); // external dto to array mapper
  },
  data() {
    return {
      prices: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async open() {
      try {
        const response = await makeApiCall(this.id);
        console.log("foo", response); // response is undefined!
        // make something with response data
      } catch (error) {
        // do nothing
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

parent.test.js:

```
import {flushPromises, mount} from "@vue/test-utils";
import * as apiModule from "./api.js";
import Child from "./Child";

jest.mock("./api.js");

it("test api call", async () => {
    // given
    const wrapper = async () => {
        return mount(Child, {
            props: {
                id: "123",
            },
        });
    };
    await flushPromises();

    // when
    wrapper.findComponent(Child).vm.$emit("open");

    // then
    const mockedResponse = {
        foo: "bar",
    };
    const response = Promise.resolve({
        status: 200,
        ok: true,
        json: () => Promise.resolve(mockedResponse),
    });
    const spy = jest.spyOn(apiModule, "makeApiCall").mockReturnValueOnce(response);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("123");

    // expect changed data fields regarding to response. This is not working!
});
```

I hope you might solve it without a interactive example, if not tell me and I'm gonna code some.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: Okay I was dumb. I need to mock my response **before** firing the custom event not afterwards (makes sense...). So the code works as expected if I'm moving

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(apiModule, "makeApiCall").mockReturnValueOnce(response);
```

before `//when` block.